# Pass return as parameter for another function

Tags: python

In the below code "roll_counts" has been used as a return for the first function and then as a parameter for the second function. my question is if I change roll_counts in second function's parameter to ABC and leave it roll_counts in the first function, the code will still work fine. i know roll_counts = 6 in parentheses but how? and why the result doesn't change when i 
i am new to python and programming, thanks in advance

```
import random as rd

def simulate_dice_rolls(N):
    roll_counts = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(N):
        roll = rd.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
        index = roll - 1
        roll_counts[index] = roll_counts[index] + 1
    return roll_counts

def show_roll_data(roll_counts):
    number_of_sides_on_die = len(roll_counts)
    for i in range(number_of_sides_on_die):
        number_of_rolls = roll_counts[i]
        number_on_die = i+1
        print(number_on_die, "came up", number_of_rolls, "times")

roll_data = simulate_dice_rolls(1000)
show_roll_data(roll_data)
```

Comment: Your indentation levels are messed up. Please correct them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blhsing 's answer is right.
But before admitting that answer, you need to understand variable scope.
There are global variables and local variables in python.
And local variables are binded in functions.
If there is same local variable to global variable in function, local variable is used without affection of global variable.
Because roll_counts is local variable of simulate_dice_rolls, you don't need to consider roll_counts in show_roll_data.

Comment: Please tolerate me if I don't make sense. I understand what you saying. I am passing 1000 to simulate_dice_roll() and then I pass simulate_dice_roll(1000) to show_roll_data, now how can it calculate  len(abc) = 6, can you please explain how show_roll_data considers len(abc) = len(roll_counts)

Comment: Because you pass simulate_dice_rolls(1000) as arguments of show_roll_data, len(roll_counts) is 6. simulate_dice_rolls(1000) = [ A, B, C, D, E, F] is it right? and you pass [A, B, C, D, E, F] to show_roll_data as roll_counts because argument of show_roll_data is "roll_counts". If you change def show_roll_count(roll_counts) to def show_roll_count(abc), then len(abc) will return 6.

Answer (score 0):

`roll_counts` in `show_roll_data(roll_counts)` is the name of a parameter and is accessible throughout the scope of the `show_roll_data` function. Its value is passed in from `roll_data` in the call `show_roll_data(roll_data)`, and has nothing to do with the local variable of the same name defined in `simulate_dice_rolls`. That's why you can rename `roll_counts` in `show_roll_data` to anything and it would still work.

Comment: I still have one confusion. if I can rename roll_counts in show_roll_data to anything then how it gets value of 6? I really want to understand how the code is connected.

Comment: I don't think `roll_counts` ever gets the value of 6, since it is a list of 6 items. It gets the value from the function call `show_roll_data(roll_data)`, so the value of `roll_data` becomes the value of `roll_counts` in function `show_roll_data`.

Comment: much appreciated your help, if I print  number_of_sides_on_die after second line of code in show_roll_data(roll_counts) it will give me a value of 6. It does make sense when I use number_of_sides_on_die = len(roll_counts). But if I rename roll_counts to ABC then it should not give me a value of 6

Comment: Why shouldn't it? The name of the parameter does not matter. The value of a parameter comes from whatever is passed in from the function call, so the value of `roll_counts` will become the value of whichever parameter you choose to name for `show_roll_data`.

Comment: Please tolerate me if I don't make sense. I understand what you saying. I am passing 1000 to simulate_dice_roll() and then I pass simulate_dice_roll(1000) to show_roll_data, now how can it calculate  len(abc) = 6, can you please explain how show_roll_data considers len(abc) = len(roll_counts)

Comment: Thank you blhsing, much appreciated